# How do I enable and use glsl #version 300 es shaders with emscripten C++ and latest firefox nightly?

Tags: c++, emscripten, glsles

and of course other browsers
I am using the emscripten C++ compiler to build a GL app.

Whenever I put the first line `"#version 300 es"` in either a vertex or fragment shader and try to run the app I get

"ERROR: unsupported shader version"

in the shader compile log.

My compile/link flags to the js binding generator phase of the emscripten build are:

```
 -s "FETCH=1" -s "ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1" -s "USE_WEBGL2=1"
```

Which supposedly enable webGL2 apis ( and by inference glsl version 300 es )

This happens even when I make the shaders almost completely empty.

I am using the firefox Nightly browser so it is the most up to date.

All the docs just sort of say "do this and it works" - frustrated :|

Answer (score 2):

It's not documented as well as it should be in samples etc, but you have to EXPLICITLY request a WebGL2 context when calling emscripten_webgl_create_context() by setting minorVerson and majorVerson on the setup argument.  Otherwise it defaults to WebGL1.0 at runtime no matter what the linker flags are set for.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by passing `-s MIN_WEBGL_VERSION=2`.

Comment: thanks will try next time I try to use it - alas there seems to be little support or corporate involvement in developing this as a distribution standard :| :|